# Set permissions on document for collect feedback workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I can't give permissions to users on the library level in advance because of customer requirements. So they want to start the collect feedback workflow on a document, assign it to a user, that user should then get access permissions to that specific document. And when the task is finished the permission should be taken away.

Been trying to copy and make changes to the collect feedback workflow to get the reviewers from the form and trigger a 2013 workflow which makes a call to a server with the item id and reviewers but when I add an action after the collect feedback action, it doesn't run until the task is finished. Which is too late.

Any ideas? is there a way to get this done?

Thanks, 
Hamed

Answer (score 0):

I guess, Workflow Impersonation feature  that are very easy to implement.

[How to Enable the Collect Feedback Workflow for a document library](http://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2012/08/09/how-to-enable-the-collect-feedback-workflow-for-a-document-library/)

Answer (score 0):

Why we need to give permission on library, user who starts will have permissions on document the user who is giving feedback should have access on task list, not on library. if user(Who provides feedback) don't have view access permission to document to view then use 2010 workflows in sp2013 so that you can use impersonation(For adding and removing permission) & collect feedback workflow.